# Run StyleCop option not showing on right click on file/inside file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, stylecop

I have StyleCop installed on my Visual Studio 2015. But, it does not give the option for running StyleCop on one particular file (on right click). StyleCop only runs on build. I am not getting the StyleCop setting option too. I have Visual Studio 2015 professional edition and I have install StyleCop from Codeplex. I have installed it using Nuget Package Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Visual StyleCop](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cac2a05b-6eb6-4fa2-95b9-1f8d011e6cae), which is an extension to Visual Studio. This preports to give the right click functionality into Visual Studio 2015

[image]

`StyleCop.Analyzers` gives you something close to the old right click functionality, but at a project level, not a file one. Let me know if you want more info on it.

---

**Update 11 Feb 2016** There is an [alpha release](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/619700) of StyleCop (4.
7.50) with Visual Studio 2015 support (but not C# 6).

**Update 16 Oct 2018** StyleCop is mainstream [available](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop) up to VS2017. Options in VS itself are provided by the extension, not the nuget package.